# ADSL Modem Goes Slower Than Dialup

Tags: adsl, adsl-router

I have two ADSL modems, the first one does not have wireless, but is configured and working fine at around 6 - 7 mbps (ADSL) on Orcon in New Zealand.

I bought a Belkin N150 wireless router to replace the first one. I configured it exactly the same as the first one, but a speed test confirms that it is running slower than dial up.

One difference I noticed is that the first modem (a linksys) came from Orcon, and didn't have an ADSL username and password set up. The Belkin modem on the other hand wouldn't let me leave the username and password field blank.

Any ideas? I am a techy guy, so it doesn't appear to be anything obvious with the settings I have missed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not all ADSL modems are created equal. Here in the UK it is well worthwhile getting a modem based on an Alcatel chipset if British Telecom is your local loop supplier. Why? Because if you have a fault and your ISP gets a BT engineer to call around, they will plug in their own Alcatel based modem and if it works, you will be charged for wasting the engineers time.

I know your situation is different, but I would still recommend using hardware supported by your ISP. That way, if something goes wrong you can say you were just doing what they wanted, so it's their fault.

If you really want flexibility, the best option is to use the supplied router/modem as just a modem (most support PPPoE) and add your own router to do the clever stuff. This will allow you to keep the same router (and thus configuration) whatever technology your ISP uses (ADSL, ADSL2+, cable modem etc.). I've been meaning to do this for a while (with a Linksys WRT54G and [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index)) but I'm still wait for my delivery of the round tuits.

Answer (score 1):

If your first modem had no authentication credentials on it, some other device on your network was authenticating, *or* you don't have to authenticate in order to connect.

You will need to call your ISP to find out which condition is true for your connection.

Unless you're talking about an admin usr/pwd for the modem's management mode, in which case the difference is not relevant.

Comment: I am talking about the username and password for the actual ADSL connection. I did call Orcon support and they said I didn't need a username or password. But with the Belkin it forces you to enter the username and password regardless. When I asked Orcon about this they told me the username and password (which is not strictly necessary) and then told me that my modem wasn't supported because it is not one of the modems that they supply.

Comment: Anyway that is just an observation, and I am not sure if this could result in a rubbish ADSL connection. It must be dropping packets or something.

Comment: Ah, well, probably best to return the Belkin and get a device your ISP supports. The Belkin probably has firmware that doesn't play nice with Orcon's equipment. Maybe just keep the working modem and put a wireless router behind it. Good luck!

Comment: Perhaps, but that is not how I saw it at the time. I was on the phone for a while, and to me it just seemed like a cop out. A way to get me off the phone so he didn't have to deal with it. 'your device is not supported ... good day'. Has anybody else had this before, belkin modems not connecting properly to your ISPs equipment?

Comment: Most of the time,"we don't support it" simply means, as you say, that the technicians aren't familiar with the modem you bought. But sometimes it means "those modems REALLY don't work with our stuff." Not all ADSL gear is totally compatible, and you have no way of knowing what kind of DSLAM equipment your ISP has...

Comment: Anyway I must mention that I am setting this up for a family member. I use a totally different ISP. Seeing as I am setting up for someone else I don't have much choice.

Comment: But another thought, I have this new ADSL wireless modem. Is there a way to use it as an 'ADSL router' only and use the original ethernet modem they supplied for the internet connection? I would need to somehow tell it to 'route' all internet traffic through one of the ethernet ports on the wireless ADSL modem, and connect that ethernet port to the existing modem. It doesn't have an uplink port on it or anything.