# My internet connection doesn't send the Accept-Encoding header

Tags: http, gzip

Whatever computer is connected to that network (router is `Netgear DGN2200`) and whatever program sends a http request, servers never get the Accept-Encoding header from me.

For example, if I go here: http://www.whatsmyip.org/http_compression/
I see:

> NO, your browser is not requesting
>   compressed content.

This problem makes websites load VERY slow for me, because most servers expect gzip request and not consider exceptions.

I can't understand if it's caused by the router, ISP or something else?

Comment: What browser, and have you tried any others?

Comment: Google chrome, firefox, ie. And all in other computers (that connected to my network) too.

Comment: OK good, I guess you have ruled that out. Have you tried connecting one of the affected computers directly to the cable mode, and then tested? If you get to that point, you will definitely be able to say router or ISP.

Comment: Mmm directly to the cable mode? is that possible? I think I need a  seperate modem (in my case it's inside the router).

Comment: Not sure what to tell you. Most people I know have a separate cable/DSL modem, and then they have their own router connected to that. I will look at your manual and see if I can find something.

Comment: I had a separate modem once too. So my only way right now is to talk with them. Thanks for the help.

Comment: As I search, I would still try downloading a Linux LiveCD and test from that to rule out any Windows security policies, firewall issues, and things like that. You seem like a sharper user, but have you updated the firmware? Currently it is at 1.0.0.36

Comment: I had too many problems with this router in the past, so I tried to upgrade it and figured out that I can't. . Can't be upgraded and lacks of some features. But the gzip problem seems newer than that router. I also tested it with a cellphone and a clean mac installation right now - same result.

Comment: Do you have a default security configuration for outboud traffic, in other words, you allow all? No port forwarding, or anything else that might interfere?

Comment: I just formatted the router and nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found this, and it appears that your modem just may not be compatible with your ISP. Frankly, I did not know that was possible, but check this out:

[ADSL Modem Goes Slower Than Dialup](https://superuser.com/questions/117256/adsl-modem-goes-slower-than-dialup)

Comment: "That way, if something goes wrong you can say you were just doing what they wanted, so it's their fault" - this is what I'm going to do. Thanks. If I'll ever know the exact problem I'll post it here.

Comment: @Zippoxer I have to take my little girl swimming now. I wish you luck, and I will check in later. Thank you for marking the answer. I appreciate it.